# jsoup call is changing url parameter from "%26" to "%2526" during execution

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I've below code

```
Document doc = null;

doc = Jsoup.connect(url).
                                    ignoreContentType(true).
                                    timeout(maxTimeout + (tryCount * maxTimeout)).
                                    userAgent("Mozilla").
                                    get();
```

I'm passing url value as

`https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/who-owns-what?q=Ratnamani+Metals+%26+Tubes`

but during debug mode, I see Document location value as

`https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/who-owns-what?q=Ratnamani+Metals+%2526+Tubes`

why does `%26` is getting changed to `%2526` ?  This results in no data getting returned back.

Comment: It's being double encoded. `&` is `%26` with url encoding, and `%` is `%25` with urlencoding.

Comment: Try using `https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/who-owns-what?q=Ratnamani+Metals+&+Tubes`

Comment: @Kayaman how to solve then ? I'm replacing `&` with `%26` before passing the url.

Comment: Looks like a Jsoup bug. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: BTW, is it allowed to scrape that site?

Comment: @Olivier I need to scrape company internal website / web app but just for query purpose I've used this website. Let me check with latest version of jsoup and update

Comment: If it's for internal use, you should query an API instead of scraping HTML.

Comment: @Olivier ok, let me discuss this change if it's fine as well. As sometimes there can be bug in UI and not in API. You were right about Jsoup bug; it's working as expected with version 1.16.1 and was not working with 1.15.4 ( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup ). Thanks for quick help.